# How do I run a WinSCP extension?

Tags: winscp, extension

I want to use the SearchText extension in WinSCP, but on their website I can only find instructions to install extensions or build them (SearchText is already installed by default).

I can't find any way in the menu to run the extension. How do I do this?

Comment: I have added a note about *executing* the extensions to the [documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP extensions are used as [Custom Commands](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_commands#extensions)

You can see the installed extensions under Options > Preferences > Commands

To run the SearchText extension from the WinSCP UI:

[image: screenshot]